# refactory might be done unproperly

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, controller, grails-3.1, urlmappings.groovy

I am a beginner trying to learn Grails 3.1. Regarding to the default, I add the following scratch on the index page:

```
<ul>
    <g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
        <li class="controller">
                        <g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link>
        </li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

At the beginning, the index page shows **no controller**. Then, I create another controller, **TodosController** for instance. Because this controller name is not nice somehow, so I want to rename it (of course, using refactory feature in Intellij IDEA) into **TodoListController**. Unfortunately, the code still remains two controllers and shows them in the index page. When I click on the link of **TodosController**, I get the error:

```
Could not resolve view with name '/todos/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Snapshot of the error is below.
[image: Could not resolve view]
I spend many times to find out where it is, but no magic thing happens to me.
Anyone got such a situation?

Comment: Stop your application, and run the `clean` command for Grails. See if that fixes it.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore: Cleaning fixes my problem. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, added it as the answer since it solved your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've confused Grails slightly. Best thing to do in this case is to stop your application and run the `clean` command and try again.  The reason is, that Grails compiled your initial Controller into the `build` directory, where the `.class` file still remains (even when the `.groovy` file is gone).  The component scan still picks the class from the class path up and you end up with the two controllers.